# Searching a vector of structs for one data member, then printing all data members that match

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to search a csv file in order to print the data found with a certain name. 
I have tried multiple suggestions found on this website but nothing seems to be working as I get constant errors. Possibly because I'm not quite understanding why my code is not working, so I would very much appreciate an explanation. My code can be found below:

```
code removed
```

Comment: Aside: writing a `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Records&)` means you can check whether the whole record is valid, rather than assume the stream has more if `fail` isn't set. At the moment you add an invalid `Record` at the end. The loop could become `for (Records awardIn; inFS >> awardsIn;) { input.push_back(awardIn); }` (or you could populate `inputs` in it's declaration, with `std::istream_iterator<Record>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off your while loop condition is not wrong, but could be simplified by using operator bool instead:

```
while(inFS)
{
    ...
}
```

Second, your usage of `std::find_if` is incorrect. The third argument must be a callable of signature `bool(Record)` (possibly `const` or ref qualified) and returns an iterator to the first match.

From your variable names and strings I guess you want to search over the `Records::recip` members in your vector. `std::find_if` is a good way to achieve this:

```
auto comp = [&search](Record const& r) { return r.receip == search; };

for (auto it = std::find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), comp);
     it != input.end();
     it = std::find_if(++it, input.end(), comp))
{
    // this loop iterates over all matches for search in Record::receip
    Record& record = *it;
    std::cout << record << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway you could give me a bit more on how this works? My professor hasn't gone over this and I'm a little lost on auto comp

Comment: `comp` is a [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11). The `auto` keyword means that the compiler should choose an appropriate data type. `comp` is basically a function here. What `find_if` does, is iterate over each element in your container (here `input`) and call `comp(element)`. If that call returns `true`, `find_if` will return with an iterator to that element.

Comment: @kingk Note that even though the `while` condition isn't wrong, it _is_ wrong to use that condition before reading 4 lines and adding a `Records` to the vector.

Comment: @Timo Thank you! Now if I want to print matching data members would I use at() at it?

Comment: I want to add what my goal is it might help. I need to search a file for reference to a name and print the award the name is associated with. If the name shows up more than once I need to print it more than once.

Comment: @kingk that's exactly what the loop does.

Comment: I get the compiler error " no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'Records') "
     cout << record << endl;

Comment: Whoever reads this I ended up creating a custom ostream operator in order to resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

The way you use find_if is incorrect, you need to use lambda to make custom search in your vector of structs. Here is more straight way:

```
for(const Record& record : input) // Iterate all records
{
    if(record.recip == search) // Check if 'recip' of the record matches the requested one
    {
        cout << "found";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`!= string::npos` is not the correct condition. `find_if` returns an iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or `last` if no such element is found. `last` is in your case `input.end()`.

You read the fields by `getline`, but when you enter the search string, you use formatted input (breaking on space). If the field contained a space in the file, you'd never be able to find it.

To make input/output easier, consider adding operator `<<` and `>>` to your class. Your current `while(!inFS.fail())` condition does not work. If you read the last `Records` struct from the file, `fail()` will *not* be true and you'll therefor try to read one complete `Records` (but failing on every line). You'll still add the erroneous `Records` struct to the `vector`.

As an alternative to the other suggestions using a lambda (which is nice) you could also add `operator==` to your `Records` - if you only want to be able to search for the same thing.

Also, read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Records {
    std::string year{};
    std::string category{};
    std::string won{};
    std::string recip{};

    // added operator to be able to compare a Records with a string
    bool operator==(const std::string& Recip) const { return recip == Recip; }
};

// custom streaming operator for reading one `Records` from a stream (like a file)
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Records& r) {
    std::getline(is, r.year, ',') && std::getline(is, r.category, ',') &&
        std::getline(is, r.won, ',') && std::getline(is, r.recip);
    return is;
}

// custom streaming operator to write a `Records` to a stream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Records& r) {
    return os << r.year << '\n' << r.category << '\n' << r.won << '\n' << r.recip << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream inFS("oscars.csv");

    if(!inFS) { // in boolean context, inFS will be false if not opened
        std::cout << "Failed to open file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<Records> input;
    Records awardIn;

    // use the custom operator>> to extract a "Records" from the file and push it back
    // inFS will be false in boolean context if the extraction failed
    while(inFS >> awardIn)
        input.push_back(awardIn);

    std::string search;
    std::cout << "Enter recipient: ";

    if(std::getline(std::cin, search)) { // check that reading succeed

        // with the added operator== you can use a normal std::find
        for(auto it = std::find(input.begin(), input.end(), search);
            it != input.end(); 
            it = std::find(std::next(it), input.end(), search)) 
        {
            // use the custom operator<< to print the Records
            std::cout << *it << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```